# Need to find highest non repeating number in custom vector

Tags: c++11

I'm creating a program, where you input n amount of mushroom pickers, they are in a shroom picking contest, they can find shroomA (worth 5 points), shroomB (worth 3 points) and shroomC (worth 15 points). I need to find the contest winner and print his/her name, but if two or more contestants have the same amount of points they are disqualified, meaning I need to find the highest non repeating result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ShroomPicker {
private:
    string name;
    long long int shroomA, shroomB, shroomC;
public:
    void Input() {
        char Name[100];
        long long int shrooma, shroomb, shroomc;
        cin >> Name >> shrooma >> shroomb >> shroomc;
        name = Name;
        shroomA = shrooma; shroomB = shroomb; shroomC = shroomc;
    }

    long long int calcPoints() {
        return shroomA * 5 + shroomB * 3 + shroomC * 15;
    }

    string winnersName() {
        return name;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<ShroomPicker> shr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ShroomPicker s;
        s.Input();
        shr.push_back(s);
    }
    long long int hiscore = 0;
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long long int temp = 0;
        temp = shr[i].calcPoints();
        if (temp > hiscore) {
            hiscore = temp;
            num = i;
        }
    }
    cout << shr[num].winnersName();
    }
```

I made this program which finds the highest score even if repeats more than once, could someone suggest how I can find the highest non repeating score?

edit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long long int temp = 0;
        temp = shr[i].calcPoints();
        if (scoreMap.find(temp) == scoreMap.end()) {
            scoreMap[temp] = Info{ i, false };
        }
        else {
            scoreMap[temp] = Info{ i, true };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorting is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sorting the list of participants in decreasing number of mushrooms picked (O[nlogn]) and then look through the list from start to finish (O[n] max).  The first participant whose number of mushrooms picked is different than those of the adjacent participants (in the sorted list) is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest (O(N)) way I can think of is to have:

```
struct Info 
{
int picker_index;
bool disqualified;
} 

// map from score to the Info object above
std::unordered_map<int, Info> scoreMap;
```

Iterate through pickers and update the map as follows:

-- If no item in the map, just add scoreMap[score] = Info {picker_index, false};

-- else, set disqualified = true on the existing item;

Once the map is constructed, find the max key in the map for which disqualified = false; similar to what you are doing now.

Comment: could you check my post edit and see if the code is correct?

Comment: the idea is correct, just a few notes:

1. you don't need to assign temp = 0; then reassign; you can just do
long long int temp = shr[i].calcPoints();

2. Replace your if case with :
  auto it = scoreMap.find(points);
  if (it == scoreMap.end()) {
   scoreMap[points] = Info{ i, false };
  }
  else {
   it->second.disqualified = true;
  }
3. Also if you are using my answer, your map should be
std::unordered_map<long long int, Info> scoreMap; so that key is same type as the points.